# sqlalchemy relationship persistancy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

new to sqlalchemy...

I have a relashionship in class Asset such that:

```
valids = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship("MyClass", primaryjoin="and_(Asset.id==MyClass.asset_id, MyClass.valid==True, MyClass.approved==True)", viewonly=True)
```

where valid and approved are columns..
now I want this to be persistant, i.e. whenever either valid or approved columns have been updated, I want the valids to get updated as well with expiry, is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need a combination of [attribute events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#attribute-events) with [`attributes.set_committed_value()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#creating-custom-load-rules) to change `.valids` every time `.valid` or `.approved` changes. Not entirely sure if that would work though.

Comment: This is what I did, but it seems like a work-around I had to manually do, is there no way to make sure primaryjoin is consistent?

Comment: Don't think there's a built-in way of doing this.